# AppEngine Users Service's User Constructor with Valid Email Returns User without user_id

Tags: google-app-engine

My understanding when reading AppEngine Users Service documentation https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects is that if we initialize a user with a valid email address, the created user should have a valid user_id. However, when I tried this code

```
from google.appengine.api import users

user = users.User('valid_email@gmail.com')
print user.user_id()
```

on both development server and real AppEngine environment, I always get

```
None
```

Is this a bug? Or do I misunderstand the document?

Answer (score 2):

If the object is instantiated as you do above, it will actually return `None`. Per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass#User_user_id):

> Note: If your application constructs the User instance, the API will
>   not set a value for user_id and it returns None

In order to use the `user_id` method, I would suggest using the `user = users.get_current_user()` structure, and if the user is not logged in, allowing them to authenticate with their Google account. For example:

```py
user = users.get_current_user()
if user:
    self.response.out.write(user.user_id())
else:
    self.response.out.write(
        "<a href=\"%s\">Sign in</a>." % users.create_login_url("/"))
```

You can find similar examples in the documentation, but after authentication, you will be able to access the `user_id` method.